# Cannot access .mdb file in flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to open and read data from a **.mdb** file in my flutter desktop app, but I failed to do this, I actually couldn't find any solution/package that helps reading data from **.mdb** files in flutter.

I appreciate any kind of help concerning this, thanks in advance!